# Bash alias to Python script -- is it possible?

Tags: python, bash, curl, scripting, multiplatform

The particular alias I'm looking to "class up" into a Python script happens to be one that makes use of the cUrl -o (output to file) option. I suppose I could as easily turn it into a BASH function, but someone advised me that I could avoid the quirks and pitfalls of the different versions and "flavors" of BASH by taking my ideas and making them Python scripts.

Coincident with this idea is another notion I had to make a feature of legacy Mac OS (officially known as "OS 9" or "Classic") pertaining to downloads platform-independent: writing the URL to some part of the file visible from one's file navigator {Konqueror, Dolphin, Nautilus, Finder or Explorer}. I know that only a scant few file types support this kind of thing using some other command-line tools (exiv2, wrjpgcom, etc). Which is perfectly fine with me as I only use this alias to download single-page image files such as JPEGs anyways.

I reckon I might as well take full advantage of the power of Python by having the script pass the string which is the source URL of the download (entered by the user and used first by cUrl) to something like exiv2 which could write it to the Comment block, EXIF User Comment block, and (taking as a first and worst example) Windows XP's File Description field. Starting small is sometimes a good way to start.

Hope someone has advice or suggestions.

BZT

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The [relevant section](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Aliases) from the Bash manual states:

> Aliases allow a string to be
>   substituted for a word when it is used
>   as the first word of a simple command.

So, there should be nothing preventing you from doing e.g.

```
$ alias geturl="python /some/cool/script.py"
```

Then you could use it like any other shell command:

```
$ geturl http://example.com/excitingstuff.jpg
```

And this would simply call your Python program.

Comment: You can also use a shebang like `#!/usr/bin/env python` in your script and do `alias geturl="/some/cool/script.py"`

Comment: Right. Many thanks to both unwind and Dennis. I've been looking into Python modules that read and write comment, EXIF and IPTC data to JPEG files, and now I suppose I'll be looking for help writing a script to either "call" cUrl or do the downloading itself along the same lines as its -o (output to file; user supplies the filename) option. Advice on this part would be appreciated as well, of course.

BZT

Answer (score 0):

I thought Pycurl might be the answer. Ahh Daniel Sternberg and his innocent presumptions that everybody knows what he does. I asked on the list whether or not pycurl had a "curl -o" analogue, and then asked 'If so: How would one go about coding it/them in a Python script?' His reply was the following:
*"curl.setopt(pycurl.WRITEDATA, fp)*

possibly combined with:

curl.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCITON, callback) "
...along with Sourceforge links to two revisions of retriever.py. I can barely recall where easy_install put the one I've got; how am I supposed to compare them?

It's pretty apparent this gentleman never had a helpdesk or phone tech support job in the Western Hemisphere, where you have to assume the 'customer' just learned how to use their comb yesterday and be prepared to walk them through everything and anything. One-liners (or three-liners with abstruse links as chasers) don't do it for me.

BZT

Comment: Okay now that's out of my system (and no "Command not found" errors either LOL)....

I found a nice wget emulator script on ActiveState.com that seems to work, but in cUrl terms it mimics the "-O" option, which unlike wget, means 'use the same file name as on the server.' How would I change it to mimic the other option? (I'd like to elicit an answer to this comment before posting the code.) BZT